# How should I implement this algorithm with zarith? Because it only works till 26

Tags: ocaml, libraries

Well, I wrote this code and I'm trying to implement the zarith library, to have access to bigger integers, otherwise I'm not able to process the algorithm more than when n=25.

```
let (~~) = Z.of_int
let (&*) = Z.mul
let (&/) = Z.div
let (&-) = Z.sub

let rec s n chamadas = 
  if n < 0 || n > 10_000 then invalid_arg "ERRO"
  else
  match n with
  | 0 -> (Z.one , chamadas + 1)
  | 1 -> (~~ 2, chamadas + 1)
  | _ -> 
    let (~~ resultado,  counter) = s (n - 1) (chamadas + 1) in
    let (~~ resultado', counter) = sum_s n 1 counter in
    (~~ 3 &* ~~ resultado &+ ~~ resultado', counter)

and sum_s n k chamadas =
  let rec aux_sum_s n k chamadas =
    if n - 2 < 1 || k > n - 2 then 
      (0, chamadas)
    else 
      let (~~ resultado,   counter) = s k chamadas in
      let (~~ resultado',  counter) = s (n - k - 1) counter in
      let (~~ resultado'', counter) = aux_sum_s n (k + 1) counter in
      (~~ resultado &* ~~ resultado' &+ ~~ resultado'', counter)
  in 
  aux_sum_s n 1 chamadas
```

that's what I understood from the documentation

Answer (score 3):

The first character of an infix operator defines its precedence (priority over other operators) and associativity (how operators with equal precedence are grouped). Therefore, your choice of prefixing the operators that work with Zarith numbers with `&` is probably the worst possible. Not only does it put all arithmetic operators on the same level, so that the multiplication has no precedence over addition, but it also groups them from right to left!

Therefore,

```
x &* y &+ z
```

is parsed as,

```
x &* (y &+ z)
```

This basically invalidates all your code.

The right way is to *append* characters to the infix operator, cf. the floating-point operators, e.g., `*.`, `+.`, etc.

So you can either do,

```
let ( *& ) = Z.mul
let ( /& ) = Z.div
let ( -& ) = Z.sub
```

or just use the [infix operators](https://antoinemine.github.io/Zarith/doc/latest/Z.html#1_Prefixandinfixoperators) that are already provided by the Zarith library together with the local opens, e.g.,

```
Z.(x * y + z)
```

is the same as,

```
x *& y *& +& z
```

provided you have the above bindings. I believe that the former is much easier to read than the latter.

In addition, you have to keep all numbers in `Z.t` if you will keep converting them back and forth, then you will lose precision with each conversion to int. It would be much easier if you will keep everything in Z.t.

Finally,

```
      let (~~ resultado,  counter) = s (n - 1) (chamadas + 1) in
```

Is not valid OCaml at all, what you wanted to say could be expressed with the following syntactically valid OCaml

```
      let (resultado,  counter) = s (n - 1) (chamadas + 1) in
      let resultado = ~~resultado in
```

But it still doesn't make much sense, since your `s` function returns the value of type `Z.t` and applying `Z.of_int` to doesn't make any sense. And using `~~` for `Z.of_int` is probably also not the best choice of name, as looks very much like negation. Zarith itself, provides the `~$` operator for that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not understanding your explanation, because where should i place "let resultado = ~~resultado in